# How to insert from a different DB into PK column?

Tags: mysql, database, join, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

Im very new to MySql and my MysqlWorkbench and Im just stucked now.
I have my staging area and also created a Core Data Ware house now.

Im trying to insert Bikeid(no PK) from table "rental_information1" (DB1) into 
idBike(PK) from the table "Bike"(DB2) which is also a FK(Bike_idBike) in the table "rental_information"(DB2)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Zhn.png) ->pic one with DB1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqgkK.png) ->pic two with DB2

I also need to join idBike(PK) and Bike_idBike(FK) together.
Insert into is not possible it gives me an error. What is the best way to accomplish this task? Thank you in advance

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Error Code:1062. Duplicate entry ´7311´ for key ´PRIMARY´

I used the query:

insert into Bike (idBike)
select BikeID from User01_turi.Rental_Information1;

Comment: Can you also share the SQL query you are running for this?

Comment: You are getting this error because the table is already having the same key for other record. Primary key should always be unique.

Comment: The SQL query is: 
_italic_ **bold** `insert into Bike (idBike)
select BikeID from User01_turi.Rental_Information1;`

Comment: The table I want to insert is empty. The problem is that i have Duplicates in the first table in DB1. I tried it with it _italic_ **bold** `select distinct`. Im just not sure if now the dependences of idBike are changed and not show the correct results.